# Mapping displays to a vm

Tags: touchscreen, udev, qemu

I want to restrict a particular display on my host to only work with a specific vm, in this case an ubuntu-core-vm that's running as a kiosk to display some simply info on a touchscreen. This is set up with ubuntu-core-vm [as described in the kiosk tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/secure-ubuntu-kiosk#1-overview). The main issue is that I want this kiosk to be running on an existing machine, not a dedicated device. I want to restrict the touchpad to the vm for security reasons in the idea that nobody can manage to type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (or some such) and drop to the host desktop. Also, when the vm is in fullscreen, the keyboard and mouse are locked to the vm (and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> doesn't release them)

I'm guessing I'll have to do something within `udev`, but not sure if I need to restrict the whole graphics card to the vm or if there's other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution in gpu passthrough. Requires using VFIO and assumes two video cards (onboard and a pci board): https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Multiheaded-NVIDIA-Gaming-using-Ubuntu-14-04-KVM-585/